# Black screen after log in but everything works?

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

Bit of a weird one, I log in like normal into my Windows 7 (64 bit) machine and am given a black screen with my mouse pointer. I know everything still works because I used superkey + R to open run and then access CMD and from there was able to launch applications I needed, which means everything runs normally but I have no desktop and minimizing my applications produces a black screen with a pointer. Even when an application is open there's no taskbar and opening the menu via superkey doesn't work.. how the heck do I fix this?! #

Thanks in advance!

-HugoNumber1

Comment: If you get the Run box open can you type in Explorer to bring up your desktop and taskbar, etc?

Comment: I didn't get the proper run box, I got the task manager version and typing explorer did nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I googled around and many sources were pointing to updating video drivers but for me this wasn't it, but if that might work for others with similar problems (here is a link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/why-is-my-screen-black-when-i-start-windows-7), for me I had to simply wait half an hour and then it just worked!